# meteor login with multiple service providers at a time

Tags: meteor

In my application,

A user login with accounts-password.

my app is related to github and I want to take data from github, so now I need my user to login with the github`(accounts-github)` so I get the data from github and display it in my application.

Is it possible to login with multiple accounts at a time?

or Is there any otherway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [accounts-meld package](https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-meld), which allows users to login from multiple services and merges the data into a single account. I think there are some limitations though, such as that accounts are merged only if they have overlapping emails.

Comment: As you said,that package says that `Meteor package to meld user accounts registered with the same email address` here in my case,the user may login with the other account and use another github account